# What makes the occurrence of the word "redhat" in the Linux sourcecode fluctuate so much

Tags: linux-kernel, source

I was browsing this website: https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/wordcount/#redhat,oracle,google,apple,microsoft

What I noticed was that at a few points in times the usage of the word "redhat" has dropped by hundreds in the kernels source. Same goes with Oracle but it's less drastic.

Was there a time when a bunch of Redhat code was pulled out of the kernel or rewritten? Were the comments simply altered?

Why was there suddenly so much mention of Oracle?

Comment: Does the web site discount email addresses in git commits?  Lots of redhat.com and oracle.com email addresses in commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many subsystems in the Linux kernel are “driven” by companies. In many cases, these have their own maintainers, who take care of development within those subsystems, and periodically send pull requests to Linus for inclusion in the next release of the kernel. As a result, large changes to those subsystems can show up suddenly, which results in sudden changes in counts of key words in those subsystems, including the names of the companies sponsoring their development (which appear in copyright statements and email addresses in the source code).

Generally speaking, a sudden increase happens because a new subsystem is merged, and a sudden decrease because it is removed. Thus, [the removal of the Fujitsu FRV port](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fd8773f9f544955f6f47dc2ac3ab85ad64376b7f) corresponds with one of the decreases in mentions of Red Hat in the graph you linked to; [the removal of the Lustre file system](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=be65f9ed267fd7d8b3146b7c4be9ecdd3e0aa3ed) corresponds with one of the decreases in mentions of Oracle.